# In the details - Explain any benefits over one loop and another. Memory writing vs memory read

Tags: javascript

I understand how picky this question is:

I was going through a PR and this made me think, there might be a better way:

**Exhibit A:**

```
for (i = 0; i < self.model.activeFilters.length; i++) {
    if (self.model.activeFilters[i].filterType === "foo") {
        includeFooFilter = false;
    }

    if (self.model.activeFilters[i].filterType === "bar") {
        includeBarFilter = false;
        includeFooFilter = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

then again, when i tried to make it better, it ended up like this, and it still doesn't seem great.

**Exhibit B:**

```
self.model.activeFilters.some(function(filter) {    
    if(includeFooFilter && filter.filterType === "foo" || filter.filterType === "bar") {
        includeFooFilter = false;
    }

    if(includeBarFilter && filter.filterType === "bar") {
        includeBarFilter = false;
    }

    if(!includeFooFilter && !includeBarFilter) {
        return true;
    }
});
// Notice i do checks before assigning property values
```

Are there any benefits over not re-assigning variable values, I guess a memory write is more expensive than a memory read?

Is this true?

Comment: Wait, if foo is in the active filters, then it should not be included? Those variable names don't make sense to me.

Comment: Argh, i know, sorry to bring it out of its original context. Indeed, this is preparing a query for a pagination task... If filters are already in, then no need to go through the process of including them again. The design is too integrated into the existing product, i guess that's why it makes me feel slightly odd about letting this through. But i wanted to centre this question more around the cost of writing memory vs reading memory, and the advantages of using a some loop rather than a for with a break.

Comment: Using `some` with a callback function will have much greater effects on performance than on whether or not you overwrite the variables. That said, *conditionally* writing a variable is much slower than always writing a variable, and no memory writes are hardly more expensive than memory reads. Though of course probably no memory is accessed at all in your code, I'd expect these two variables to reside in registers.

Comment: @Bergi - That's fantastic to know, i completely trust you but i am doing a PR, any sources for this? Thanks mate!

Comment: No sources, just a bit of experience - which also tells me that no matter what you are doing, *those* differences will be absolutely insignificant. [Do not prematurely micro-optimise!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation) Aim for readable code first, and your two snippet are stylistically different enough already.

Comment: Legend, thanks mate. I learnt a lot here. I'll keep the loop as it is (approve with suggestions) :D. Thank you.